# Arrange and combine values in table in R by unique identifier

Tags: r, apply

I have the following data:

```
ID<-c(001,002,003,003,004,005)
Email<-c("tom@abc.com","jane@abc.com","jim@abc.com","jim@abc.com","tom@abc.com","mike@abc.com")
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(ID,Email))
```

I want to create a table where the ID numbers for each person's email address will be shown in table format.

```
Email           IDs
jane@abc.com    002
jim@abc.com     003
mike@abc.com    005
tom@abc.com     001, 004
```

I've tried an apply function, `tapply(df$ID,df$Email, FUN=length`, but am only getting non-unique count.

```
jane@abc.com    1
jim@abc.com     2
mike@abc.com    1
tom@abc.com     2
```

Answer (score 3):

With a data.table, this is simple:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c("001","002","003","003","004","005"),
    email = c("tom@abc.com","jane@abc.com","jim@abc.com","jim@abc.com","tom@abc.com","mike@abc.com"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , .(idlist = paste(unique(id), collapse = ", ")), by = email]
```

Comment: or `res <- dt[, .(IDS = paste0(ID, collapse = ", ")), Email]` if you are happy with string values

Comment: @Bulat - I will edit my answer to use this as it's more directly what the OP asked for. Thanks!

Comment: @DanY the solution you provided collapses the IDs into one cell. However, I only want to return unique IDs in each cell. In your solution you'll see that tom@abc.com has "003, 003" as the result. The 003 should be listed once.

Comment: Just wrap `id` with `unique()`.  I've updated my answer to now include this.